# Cannot fix Windows 10 boot record

Tags: windows, windows-10, bootloader

### BACKGROUND

I had an ASRock server motherboard with Windows 10 installed on an NVME disk. The motherboard failed (i.e. will not power up). I replaced the MB with a SuperMicro X10Dai MB.

I attached the NVME drive to a PCI-E adapter. The X10Dai recognizes the drive. When the system boots, I load the boot manager and select the Windows boot manager. However, the system is unable to find Windows.

### What I have tried so far: method 1

Booted into a Windows recovery USB and selected repair boot. This fails to work.

### What I have tried so far: method 2

From the Windows recovery USB, I entered the command prompt and did the following:

```
c:\>diskpart

diskpart> select disk 0
diskpart> select vol 3 #the EFI volume
diskpart> assign letter N:
diskpart> exit

c:>cd N:
N:> bootrec / fixboot
```

At the point I receive the message ACCESS IS DENIED.

```
N:> bootrec /fixmbr
```

This is successful

```
N:>bootrec /fixboot
```

At the point I receive the message ACCESS IS DENIED.

### What I have tried so far: method 3

```
c:\>diskpart

diskpart> select disk 0
diskpart> select vol 3 #the EFI volume
diskpart> assign letter N:
diskpart> exit

C:>format N: /FS:FAT32
C:>bcdboot C:\windows /s N: /f
C:>cd N:
N:>bootrec /fixboot
```

At the point I receive the message ACCESS IS DENIED.

```
N:>bootrec /rebuildbcd

N:>bootrec / fixboot
```

At the point I receive the message ACCESS IS DENIED.
This method detects no installations of Windows (however, I am able to access the Windows partition successfully in the command prompt)

**What can I do to fix the boot record?**

I know how to boot into Ubuntu Live if there is a solution involving Ubuntu (though I would need instructions of what to do)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a backup of all the data you need from the NVMe drive? That would be the first thing to do if you can - you didn't mention it so I thought it best to be sure.

Comment: Once you've done that, have you searched for "SuperMicro X10Dai boot from nvme"? There appears to be quite a bit of reading material available if the [Supermicro instructions](https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=22269) don't work for you.

Comment: Yes I do. Under a worst case scenario, I will not lose anything (except maybe some preference settings)

Comment: After a little more thought, maybe pursuing the "ACCESS IS DENIED" problem is the way to go.

Comment: The "ACCESS IS DENIED" route is the one I am researching.

Comment: If you have spare NVMe drives, have you tried installing Windows on a blank one? Sometimes the long way round is faster.

Comment: Also, if it's work-related where productivity needs to be restored, I would very definitely consider updating to more recent processors (and M/B and RAM, of course). It looks like it's using six-year-old parts; current parts in the same price range as the old ones will be a *lot* faster in many scenarios. IMHO.

Comment: It's a personal workstation. As I mentioned, the previous MB died. Since I have all parts except a MB, it was cheaper to purchase a used MB off ebay. I am presently in Ubuntu Live and I am imaging the OS and relevant hidden partitions to another USB disk. I will then try a clean install of Windows and hopefully it will have a working bootloader. I will then engage in some trial and error to see if I can fool the new install by replacing it with the backed up image.

Comment: Ahh, quite a nice bit of kit for personal use, so I see why you want to preserve as much as possible of the original. You could wait a bit longer to see if someone who's actually done the same thing happens along, but I too would be trying a clean Windows install by now.

Comment: I don't have a solution to this problem. A fresh install had the same bootloader problem. I was able to install Windows on a SATA drive thus ruling out some sort of general motherboard error. I will reach out directly to SuperMicro to see if they have any guidance on the bootloader problem when booting from a PCI-E NVME.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer after more research. The X10Dai supports NVME via PCI-E card but is unable to boot from the device. It can only boot from SATA/SAS.

https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=33952

> Some X10 M/B can't boot from NVMe drive with OS.  X10DAI is one of them.  Please use SATA or SAS drive.

Comment: Apparently it is possible: [Supermicro X10DRi boot from NVMe (modified BIOS inside)](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/supermicro-x10dri-boot-from-nvme-modified-bios-inside.30262/).

Comment: I did come across that BIOS modding article but it is too risky for me to try. To add another screw to the solution is a Supermicro support solution that says this very thing is possible (https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=22269). However, I tried this exact solution and it did not work; so, in practice this solution is that it is not possible. I will probably follow up with Supermicro to ask them to reconcile the conflicting support solutions.